# how to implement JSNI in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, jsni

I have experience in GWT but know nothing about JSNI or Javascript . i am searching for few days for JSNI now but i am not able to understand how to implement JSNI in my GWT project.

where and how i will add a javascript file in my GWT project, where i will write my javascript?

and then i want to call a javascript method from java/GWT

Here is a simple example of how to code a JSNI method that puts up a JavaScript alert dialog:

```
          public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
          $wnd.alert(msg);
           }-*/;
```

but where will i add this code in my GWT project

i hvae just created a new project "HelloJSNI" and in my class HelloJSNI.java  , i added this code , am i doing write ?

```
      public void onModuleLoad() {
        alert("call from java to Javascript");

    }
    public void testJSNI(int amt, float interestRate,
            int term){
        Window.alert("call from javascript to java");
    }
    public static native void alert(String msg) /*-{
//    $wnd.alert(msg);
      $wnd.testJSNI=
          $entry(@com.jsni.client.HelloJSNI::testJSNI(IFI));

    }-*/;
}
```

will i be able to see "hello JSNI "?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please first understand using the Java "Native" keyword without even considering GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and best place to learn about JSNI is [this article](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

If you have any more specific questions after reading that article, please ask here on SO.

Comment: thanks, the code i mentioned in my question is from the article u mentioned, but in that article its never menionted that where to put this code, where to write javascript code ?

Comment: You write that method alongside your Java code, and call it as a normal Java method. See examples further down in that link.

Comment: here it is: package mypackage;public MyUtilityClass{    public static int computeLoanInterest(int amt, float interestRate,                                          int term) { ... }    public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{       $wnd.computeLoanInterest =          $entry(@mypackage.MyUtilityClass::computeLoanInterest(IFI));    }-*/;}

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#calling

Comment: from this code i added in my question , i am having this exception Missing qualifier on instance method 'com.jsni.client.HelloJSNI.testJSNI'

Comment: Your code sample seems to be calling through JSNI back to a regular Java method, which isn't necessary. If you want to call `Window.alert()` you can just simply do so.

Comment: thanks, ur code working , now i am succesfully calling a JSNI method from my java, but if i want to call some java method from my javascript how will i do that ?

Comment: This is also covered in the link. But here is some sample code to get you started. https://gist.github.com/2018382